# Update HTML text automatically from file

Tags: html, xml

I run a Wordpress website for a restaurant, where I manually get to update some of the text (the week's menu) which I receive from the chef by mail in a Word file every monday morning.

I have been thinking if there is any way to avoid update every text snippet each week (Monday's dish is one WPBakery text block element, Tuesday's dish in another etc.), which makes this pretty time consuming. Especially because the site is in two languages.

At best, the chef himself could update an Excel (or XML?) file which he then sends to me. I double-check everything and then upload it to the CMS and all the text snippets gets automatically updated. Is this possible?

Thanks!